# Get the current user to resolve the hibernate tenant - multi-tenancy

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, dropwizard

I would like to use hibernate multi-tenancy in my Dropwizard app. I've implemented a `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` that has a `resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier` method to decide which database the user should be connected to.

In this method I need to get the user that is part of the current request. E.g. The username that is passed in when posting to the server. This will then allow me to figure out the organisation associated with the user so I can decide what database the user should connect to.

```
import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;

public class MultiTenantCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver
        implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

        // Calculate the database tenant id based on the user
        return "TenantID";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't see how this can be done. I need a method that gives me the current user from Dropwizard to know which databse the user should be pointed at.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The answer is heavily depends on the way you manage authentication (`dropwizard-auth` or some custom implementation). Anyway, in the end it must be some `ThreadLocal` which you set whenever you obtain current user at corresponding level (http filter, rest resource, etc), and later you can access this `ThreadLocal` variable from any other place in your app, e.g. from `MultiTenantCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`.

Comment: For this to work does it assume that the execution of each endpoint is sequencial instead of possibly being multi-threaded? 
E.g. If two users call an endpoint at the same time, user 1 might authenticate first (and set the variable), then user 2 authenticates before the `resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier` method is called for user 1. 
Can this happen or will it be okay?

Comment: Each call to an endpoint is served on separate thread, so ThreadLocal variable should be safe in this case. But it won't work out of the box if you have your DB queries executed in different thread - thread locals must be propagated into that thread too.